# bash difference between export $(/something) and "something"

Tags: bash, maven

I tried setting my JAVA_HOME variable to start using maven. this is what i had in my bash profile (on my mac)

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/libexec/java_home"
```

and that seems to work just fine when i run `$JAVA_HOME -V` but maven doesn't think it's set properly. i've read on some blogs to do:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

what's the difference? and what is the second one better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/usr/libexec/java_home` is NOT the path to the Java home directory itself, but an *executable* whose *output* is the path to the home folder.

This is why you need the 2nd form, which uses command substitution (`$(...)`) to capture the output from said executable and assigns it to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

The first instance sets the value of `JAVA_HOME` to the string `"/usr/libexec/java_home"`. The second sets it to the standard output of the command `/usr/libexec/java_home`.

Try running `/usr/libexec/java_home` to see what its output is. That is likely what you want your actual `JAVA_HOME` to be set to.

Answer (score 1):

$(command) in bash executes whatever the command in the parenthesis is.

For example

```
$ echo $(echo hello $(echo world))
```

results in

```
hello world
```

whereas

```
export JAVA_HOME="string"
```

just sets the variable JAVA_HOME to that string